# SASS, how :last-child of ::after

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, less, pseudo-element

Someone can explain how it does work on SASS?

```
ul.breadcrumbs
    margin-top: 30px
    display: flex
    list-style-type: none
    gap: 20px
    li.bread-item
        &::after
            content: ">"
            margin-left: 20px
    &:last-child::after
        content: ""
```

I'm trying to remove the last after element from li in the ul list

Answer (score 0):

`:last-child` asks "Am I the last child?", rather than "What is the last child of this element?". With that in mind then you can see that you're targeting `ul` elements which are the last child of whatever their parent element is. All you have to do is indent the rule so that it's targeting the li instead.

```
ul.breadcrumbs
    margin-top: 30px
    display: flex
    list-style-type: none
    gap: 20px
    
    li.bread-item
        &::after
            content: ">"
            margin-left: 20px
        &:last-child::after
            content: ""
```

That'll work as you're intending and remove the `>` from the last `li`.